# What justifies the use of asymptotic momentum state?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, momentum, s-matrix-theory

The LSZ scattering approach starts with initial and final asymptotic momentum states. But we know that $\langle k' | k\rangle = \delta^3(k'-k)$, which means that it is not a properly normalizable state. But we still talk in scattering experiment of initial state being in $|k\rangle$ and final state being in $|k'\rangle$ and compute scattering amplitude. Even if we restrict ourselves to realistic scenario where a wavepacket has a finite "width" or variance so that it is not sharply localized in one momentum state, this does not deflect the question of normalization.

*My question thus is, what are the reasons that allow us to deflect this concern?*

Comment: The concept you are looking for is the [rigged Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigged_Hilbert_space)

Comment: @BySymmetry OK, I know rigged Hilbert space. But how I read things is that rigged Hilbert space justifies spectral analysis to continuous spectrum, but it still is not the case we can think of $|k\rangle$ as a valid state to be evolved by Hamiltonian of a theory. Of course my interpretation could be wrong, and if rigged Hilbert space justifying $|k\rangle$ is canonical understanding, then the question is answered.

Comment: @BySymmetry After all, still $\langle k|k\rangle \neq 1$, so this violates probabilistic interpretation..

Comment: This might be nothing, but a couple vague ideas occur to me. Even in the absence of normalizable states, ratios between scattering coefficients can still be meaningful. I think a variant of Fermi's Golden Rule might also be applicable here.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no problem if you use appropriate initial and final states that are modeled as a superposition of different momentum eigenstates
\begin{equation} 
|{1_{\vec{k}}}\rangle^{\text{physical}} \equiv \int \frac{d^3k'}{(2\pi)^3}  f(\vec{k}, \vec{k}' ) |1_{\vec{k}'}\rangle \, ,
\end{equation}
where $f(\vec{k}, \vec{k}' ) $ is a smearing function, e.g. a Gaussian
\begin{equation} 
f^{\text{Gauss}}(\vec{k}, \vec{k}' )  \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{(\vec{k}-\vec{k}')^2}{2\sigma^2}} \, .
\end{equation}
Such physical states are normalized
$$ \langle 1_{\vec{k}}| 1_{\vec{k}}\rangle = 1  $$ 
 which follows immediately from the normalization of the Gaussian smearing function.

---

A more common trick, however, is to focus on ratios of scattering amplitudes like $$\frac{\langle f \vert S \vert i\rangle}{\langle f \vert i \rangle}$$ or probabilities of the form
$$\frac{|\langle f \vert S \vert i\rangle|^2}{\langle f \vert f \rangle \langle i \vert i \rangle}$$